# Stored Procedure calculating employee earnings

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

I have following stored procedure in a C# win forms application which calculates employee earnings based on attendance as follows.

Note that a shift is 12 hours and employees mark attendance for in and out of each shifts. Also salary period is from beginning to end of a month (1<sup>st</sup> to 28<sup>st</sup> / 30<sup>th</sup> / 31<sup>st</sup>).

Related tables are:

- Employee (`emp_id`, `initials`, `surname`, `basic_sal`, `budj_allowance`)
- Attendance (`emp_id`, `in_time`, `out_time`, `shift`)
- Rank (`rank_id`, `shift_rate`)

**Calculations**

1. Work Days - This is the number of days a particular employee has worked and this value is taken from Attendance table.
2. Day Offs - An employee is entitled for maximum of 4 day offs for a month and if more than four days have been taken by an employee, remaining days will be marked as "Leave days".
3. No of Extra Shifts - This value is taken by this formula.

   ```
   [Total Shifts - total days worked]
   ```
4. Basic Salary - This is taken from employee master table
5. Budgetary Allowance - All employees are paid Rs.1,000/- as budgetary allowance
6. No Pay Days - This is calculated from the formula

   ```
   [(No of days in the month-04) - days worked]
   ```
7. Less No Pay Amount - This is calculated from the formula.

   [((Basic Salary + Budgetary Allowance) / (No of Days in the month-04)) x No Pay Days]
8. Amount for the EPF - This is calculated from the formula

   ```
   [Basic Salary + Budgetary Allowance - Less No Pay Amount]
   ```
9. Overtime Amount - This is calculated from the formula

   ```
   [Amount for the EPF - (Extra Shift Rate x Work Days)]
   ```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Earnings] @fromDate datetime, @toDate datetime 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
-- Declaring a variable to hold on of days in the month.
DECLARE @No_of_days int
SELECT @No_of_days = DATEDIFF(day,@fromDate,DATEADD(day,1,(@toDate)))

-- Declaring a constant to hold no of off days allowed in a month
DECLARE @Day_offs_allowed int
SELECT @Day_offs_allowed=4

--This is a reference to identify month and year of everyrecord. example - **"APR2014"**

DECLARE @SalRef char(20)
SELECT @SalRef= REPLACE(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(12),CONVERT(date,@fromDate,107),106),1,3,''),' ','')

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here


SELECT     Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ', ' + Employee.Surname AS Name, 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)) AS work_days,

                        CASE WHEN (@No_of_days - (COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))) >= @Day_offs_allowed) 
                        THEN @Day_offs_allowed 
                        ELSE (@No_of_days - (COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)))) 
                        END AS day_offs, 

                        CASE WHEN (@No_of_days - (COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))) >= @Day_offs_allowed) 
                        THEN @No_of_days - (COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))) - @Day_offs_allowed 
                        ELSE 0 
                        END AS leave_days, 

                        COUNT(Attendance.shift) - COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)) AS extra_shifts, 
                        Rank.Shift_Rate,  
                        (COUNT(Attendance.shift) - COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)))* rank.Shift_Rate AS Extra_Shift_Amount, 
                        employee.Basic_Sal, 
                        employee.budj_allowance,
                        (@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed)- COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)) AS no_pay_days,
                        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(((employee.basic_sal+employee.budj_allowance) / (@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed) )) * ((@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed)- COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)))) AS less_no_pay_amt, 
                        employee.basic_sal+employee.budj_allowance-CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),((employee.basic_sal+employee.budj_allowance) / (@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed) ) * ((@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed)- COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))))AS amt_for_epf, 
                        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),((Rank.Shift_Rate*(COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))))-((((employee.basic_sal+employee.budj_allowance)-(((employee.basic_sal+employee.budj_allowance) / (@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed)) * (@No_of_days-@Day_offs_allowed- COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time))))))))) AS over_time_amt, 
                        @salRef AS Reference 
FROM         Employee INNER JOIN
                      Attendance ON Employee.Emp_ID = Attendance.EID INNER JOIN
                      Point ON Attendance.PID = Point.PID INNER JOIN
                      Rank ON Employee.Rank = Rank.Rank_ID 
WHERE Attendance.in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @toDate, 102)                       
GROUP BY Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ', ' + Employee.Surname, Rank.Shift_Rate, Employee.Basic_Sal, Employee.budj_allowance  
ORDER BY Employee.Emp_ID

END
```

Questions:

1. Can this be further optimized?
2. Are there any notable flows?
3. Is a stored procedure suitable for this requirement?

Comment: It looks well made. I do think a procedure is suitable for this. Nothing really jumps at me other than the large number of `CONVERT()` functions. Guessing your source columns are `DATETME`? If you can post the execution plan this would help us look for anything that is not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my thoughts on your proc.

**The Good**

Good job on commenting out sections that are not so obvious to figure out. I had very little difficulty understanding it, your code is much cleaner than the average SQL post on this site. I would say a stored procedure is the correct type of database object for this, since it sounds like it will be called regularly based on its nature.

**Improvements**

1. Even though SQL engine is set up to where you don't always need to use delimiter `;` it is good practice to explicitly use them. `DECLARE @No_of_days int` becomes `DECLARE @No_of_days int;` etc. throughout.
2. To avoid errors when creating a proc, it is a good idea to `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[sp_Earnings];` for instance.
3. This may just be personal preference, but I think `SET` is less ambiguous to set variables, so `SELECT @Day_offs_allowed=4;` would become `SET @Day_offs_allowed=4;`. This helps to differentiate them from nested queries and such.
4. I think this is a bit odd: 
   `SELECT @SalRef= REPLACE(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(12),CONVERT(date,@fromDate,107),106),1,3,''),' ','')`. 
   I would be tempted to instead use
    `SET @SalRef = CONCAT( DATEPART(Mm, @fromDate), '/', DATEPART(Yy, @fromDate) )`. 
   This reference will look slightly different, e.g. "04/2014" but achieve the same purpose more elegantly plus you can sort them in order more easily numerically.
5. A point on formatting. When using long nested statements it is good practice to use line break and tabs to make it easier to read. For example:

   ```
   (COUNT(Attendance.shift) - COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)))* rank.Shift_Rate AS Extra_Shift_Amount
   ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   (COUNT
       (Attendance.shift) - COUNT(        
           DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, Attendance.in_time)    
       )        
   )* rank.Shift_Rate AS Extra_Shift_Amount,
   ```

Other than that I think your code is good.